Async Component Nuxt
I would like to make asynchronous components and load their names from the database, for example.
const dynamicComponent = () => defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`~/components/pages/${componentName}.vue`))

then I create a loaded component
const app = createApp(dynamicComponent(), {
...
})

everything works great until I write some asynchronous operation in created component, e.g.
<script lang="ts" setup>
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})
await promise

I have the following warning and the component does not appear
[Vue warn]: Component : setup function returned a promise, but no  boundary was found in the parent component tree. A component with async setup() must be nested in a  in order to be rendered.
I tried surrounding components as suspense - nothing worked

"I tried surrounding components as suspense", can you show your attempt?  If dynamicComponent is the root component then it would need another component as it's parent with <Suspense> to avoid the warning.

I think a possible solution would look something like this

How is thus related to Nuxt? You don't use createApp directly there, so it's unclear what your real case looks like. You need to provide all relevant info for a proper answer
